# mouse right button mapped to work for traversing back in Jelly Bean

Tags: android

We have changed some part of code in `framework/base/services/input/inputreader.cpp to make the mouse right click work for traversing back.

```
case BTN_RIGHT:
    mBtnRight = rawEvent->value;
    break;
```

to

```
case BTN_RIGHT:                       
    mBtnBack = rawEvent->value;
    break;
```

It is receiving all the mouse events.when I click the mouse right button it is receiving motion events as well as key events.But it is not able to dispatch key events.

Its giving error:

---

```
D/InputDispatcher( 1229): dispatchKey - eventTime=1352984476958100000, deviceId=2, source=0x2002, policyFlags=0x42000000, action=0x1, flags=0x0, keyCode=0x4, scanCode=0x0, metaState=0x0, repeatCount=0, downTime=1352984476958100000
D/InputDispatcher( 1229): Waiting for application to become ready for input: AppWindowToken{41294900 token=Token{411c0f90 ActivityRecord{41301e68 com.android.calculator2/.Calculator}}} - Window{413ff3c0 com.android.calculator2/com.android.calculator2.Calculator paused=false}.  Reason: Waiting because the focused window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.
D/InputDispatcher( 1229): findFocusedWindow finished: injectionResult=-1, timeSpentWaitingForApplication=0.0ms
```

---

Is it a bug in Jelly Bean?

Comment: I get the same message if I hook up a PS3 gamepad to my tablet and press down both analog joysticks at the same time. It is almost like there is some racecondition somewhere that does not like simultaneous events.

Answer (score 2):

To make mouse Right_click to work as Back Button do the following changes. it is working for me.

```
 in function reset(InputDevice* device) {

            replace mBtnRight = device->isKeyPressed(BTN_RIGHT); line to

                    mBtnBack =  device->isKeyPressed(BTN_RIGHT);

             and 
  in function process(const RawEvent* rawEvent) {

              remove  3 lines   case BTN_RIGHT:
                                mBtnRight = rawEvent->value;
                                break;
                     and Add "case BTN_RIGHT:" before case BTN_BACK:" as shown below

                     case BTN_RIGHT:
                     case BTN_BACK:                       
                     mBtnBack = rawEvent->value;
                     break;
```

/*Thats all it is working for me. */