# Disable GotoHome behaviour provided by a mouse middle button click on Android

Tags: android, android-homebutton

In a business context (not commercial app), I need to avoid middle button click behaviour, that is to say displaying Home Screen

I spent hours browsing Stackoverflow pages, and the conclusion is often :

- it's not possible, regarding obvious security considerations

My need is a bit different :

- **I use a connected mouse, I don't want to override device hardware button.**
- **my app will only be use in a business context, not publicly.**

Details :

- my device is a Samsung Galaxy 3 (Model Number GT-P5210, Android version 4.2.2)
- the mouse is a classical 3-buttons mouse (left-click, mouse wheel, right-click)

I can accept :

- to override OnPause, OnUserLeaveEvents (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938986/2773267 doesn't work in my case)
- to modify my manifest
- to use a service (watchdog-like), that prevent Home display
- to root the device (last-chance solution):

  - modify /system/usr/keylayout (part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311126/2773267 answer)
  - all others solution, excepted those I can't accept :)

I can't accept :

- using service (as in http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/)

--
Thanks, Jerome.

Excuse my awful english, I'm french !

Comment: Any luck with this? Even with Oreo and the new mouse support this seems impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this 3 lines to the manifest solved the problem.
Firstly it didn't work because I made a mistake on activity name

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Thanks !

--

Jerome

Comment: Select default screen on the device comes up?

Comment: default screen is materialized by the app, whatever home intent is triggered (mouse or device)

Comment: I get the question what is the the default screen of the device, I recon that if I select my app it will start up att the device start?? Or? I mean a bad idea doing as suggested? I found very little to do about the centre button, but the wheel works find doing nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your app as a HOME-screen replacement. In this case, your app IS the HOME-screen, so pressing HOME does nothing.